# Grafico en access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013

Buenas tengo un problema que es dificil de explicar si no es con una imagen.
Quiero hacer grafico en Access 2013, me pasa igual en formularios que en informes. Inserto el grafico con un cierto tamaño, ver el marco naranja en la imagen. Pero el grafico sale ocupando solo una parte pequeña de ese área. Como una cuarta parte en la esquina superior izquierda. Me pasa siempre con todos los formularios, bases de datos etc.
Alguna pista de como hacer que el grafico ocupe todo el área deseada?
saludos

[image: grafico Access 2013]